# Thread not access view

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have a class that populates a listview, but it is with an error stating that the thread can not handle the view, I wonder if anyone knows of a better way of putting a processdialog before showing the list, Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables
static final String URL = "sample.com";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_NAME = "nome";
static final String KEY_END = "endereco";
static final String KEY_TEL = "telefone";
static final String KEY_BAI = "bairro";

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
//private Handler handler;

ListAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Test");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    //handler = new Handler();

    new Thread(){            
         public void run() {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "loading...");                      
                }
            });             
             loadList();
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
     }.start();

    lv = getListView();     

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DescriptionActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("nome", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("endereco", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString());
            in.putExtra("telefone", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString());
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}

public void loadList(){

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_END, parser.getValue(e, KEY_END));
        map.put(KEY_TEL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TEL));
        map.put(KEY_BAI, parser.getValue(e, KEY_BAI));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        menuItems.add(map);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
            R.layout.list_row_lojas,
            new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_END,  KEY_TEL, KEY_BAI }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.cost, R.id.bairro });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

> 04-24 23:03:50.871: E/AndroidRuntime(26159):
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "loading...");                      
                }
            });
```

instead of

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "loading...");                      
                }
            });
```